# Reuse Cursor object in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, mongodb-query, pymongo

For some reason I need use same cursor twice, one for iterate, another for functions, after iterate cursor can't use, So I need input mongo command twice.

I want to make a cursor use it twice, I try to use lambda as cursor, but system told me 'function' object is not iterable.

Comment: Did you try `rewind()` method of cursor ?

Comment: iterate under function !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is use the [`rewind()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind) method to rewind the cursor to its unevaluated state. But as mentioned in the documentation:

> Future iterating performed on this cursor will cause new queries to be sent to the server, even if the resultant data has already been retrieved by this cursor.

If you do not want to sent new queries to the server then you can use the `list` class to return a list of document. But this will load all the data in memory.